# analytic extension

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in the annulus $1<|z|<2$ and there exist a sequence of polynomials converging to $f$ uniformly on every compact subset of this annulus.  Show $f$ has an analytic extension to all of the disc $|z|<2$.

Comment: I think this has to do with Laurent series but I could be wrong.  I also thought of maybe showing $f$ has a removable singularity at 0, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the Laurent series for $f$ in the annulus and calculate the coefficients of negative powers using the polynomial approximation.

Conclude that the Laurent series is a power series.

A power series that converges in the annulus already converges in the disc.

Comment: "A power series that converges in the annulus already converges in the disc" Why is this true?

Comment: A power series with powers of $z$ has a radius ofconvergence. It converges inside the radius, and it diverges outside (the cercle itself is a more delicate question). So, when you know it converges for points of radius 1.5, it automatically converges of all smaller ones.