# More clarification on analytic extension

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in the annulus $1<|z|<2$ and there exist a sequence of polynomials converging to $f$ uniformly on every compact subset of this annulus.  Show $f$ has an analytic extension to all of the disc $|z|<2$.

It was answered on 
[analytic extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150051/analytic-extension).

Can anyone please show me how to calculate the coefficients of negative powers using the polynomial approximation???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to have uniform polynomial approximation on a circle $C$ inside the annulus, say $|z|=c, 1<c<2$. Then if $||P_m-f||_{\infty}=\max_{|z|=c}|P_m(z)-f(z)| \to 0$ and $f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ we have by the triangle inequality

$2\pi|a_n|=|\int_Cf(z)z^{-n-1}dz| \le |\int_C(P_m(z)-f(z))z^{-n-1}dz|+|\int_CP_m(z)z^{-n-1}dz|\le$

$\le \int_C|P_m(z)-f(z)||z^{-n-1}dz| \le 2\pi c^{-n}||P_m-f||_{\infty} \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$

for all $n \le -1$ since then $-n-1 \ge 0$ and $P_m(z)z^{-n-1}$ is a polynomial too so has zero integral on $C$ by Cauchy

Comment: And this $||P_m-f||_{\infty}=\max_{|z|=c}|P_m(z)-f(z)| \to 0$ holds because of uniformly convergence ?

Comment: that is the definition of uniform convergence as $|P_m-f|$ gets small uniformly in $z \in C$ which is equivalent to $\max|P_m-f|$ getting small- as noted it is enough to hold on a circle (or more generally a rectifiable Jordan curve), no need to hold on compact sets within the full annulus

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: sorry...but what about n= -infinity, is still an=0?

Comment: $n$ is always finite - $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ means the usual sum where $n=0,1,-1,2,-2...$